# how to get objects from a json array in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working on an iPhone app which involves using json-framework.I am getting array using NSURL

```
[{"firstName":"X","lastName":"Y","id":1},{"firstName":"A","lastName":"B","id":2}]
```

How can i get these 2 objects as like if i query for id=1, the O/P is

```
id=1
firstName:X
lastName:Y
```

and putting it in a table.
I am googling the stuff from many days but didn't get any solution.
Please help me out , explanation through code is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your target SDK is ios4 or higher, you can use this project

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Once you add the source to your project, just

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```

and convert your Json string as follows

```
jsonResponse = [string JSONValue];
```

The method will fail if you don't have the full Json array in your string, but you can keep appending strings until it doesn't fail

To follow up for codejunkie's request below
you can assume in your data structure that the `jsonResponse` is an `NSArray`
In other implementations take care to test the response for NSArray or NSDictionary

```
NSArray * myPeople = [string JSONValue]; 
NSMutableDictionary * organizedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary * p in myPeople) {
    [organizedData setValue:p forKey:[p valueForKey:@"id"]];
}
    // now you can query for an id like so
    // [organizedData valueForKey:@"1"]; and your output will be what you wanted from the original question
    // just don't forget to release organizedData when you are done with it
```

Comment: Hi, thank for reply. I have done it, bt now the problem is that i am getting errors when i put the classes folder in framework folder in my project.

Comment: Hi, thank for reply. I have done it, bt now the problem is that i am getting errors when i put the classes folder in framework folder in my project.
it gives several errors in streamparser files.

Comment: Hey, no problem. What sort of errors?  There are several different versions, I would suggest starting at V3.0 and working your way up
https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads

Comment: I am working on project in which i can display first name and last name in a table row. I am thinking to do this on the basis of their id values and putting them in table rows. Any idea how i can do this, i mean how can i get objects separately.?

Comment: @codejunkie.  I edited again to help you along.  As for the table row.  Look up questions on here related to UITableView and good luck.  Can you upvote or mark as answered if you feel your original question was resolved.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am looking for how to get json data , and found these 2 methods
- (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundArray:(NSArray *)array { //Process array
}
- (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundObject:(NSDictionary *)dict { //Process object
}
Can some1 please tell me how i can use these in my case.

Comment: You don't have to dive into all the files in the SBJson project to parse the Jsonarray.  In objective-c your Jsonarray is technichally a string.  Calling [string JSONValue] will return an array of dictionaries in your example data.  The code above (I removed parantheses around the NSArray *) should give you access to all of your data.  Does the logger output what you want now?

Comment: I used the code: 

NSArray * myPeople = [string JSONValue]; 
// this loop iterates through each person returned from the Json Array
for (NSDictionary * person in myPeople) {
    NSLog(@"test for person information %@", person);
    NSLog(@"first name is - %@\nlast name is - %@", [person valueForKey:@"firstName"], [person valueForKey:@"lastName"]);
cell.textLabel.text = [person valueForKey:@"firstName"];
}

But, every time I get the last object of dictionary in the table. It works fine on the console. Please suggest a way where I can get all the objects of the dictionary.

Comment: How to extract those dictionaries from the array separately, i mean if i can populate the names in the table rows on the basis of their id's. e.g, for id=1 its dictionary1 and in first table row , it will print first and last name from dictionary1.Similary for the others ID's

Comment: @codejunkie I tried to move this conversation to a chat, but you are not eligible.  I updated the bottom chunk of my code to demonstrate how to build a dictionary out of your array and use that to access your people by id's.  Now I believe your initial question should be resolved.  We covered Json parsing, reading the data, and organizing the data.  Why no upvotes or mark as answered?

Comment: I had another query, the JSON data that I obtain from a URL is : [{"firstName":"X","lastName":"Y","id":1},{"firstName":"A","lastName":"B","id":2}]. I want to display them in a cell for a table in a sorted form on the basis of their id. Can u please guide me

Comment: I wish you could chat. If you want to sort the objects, they have to be in an array and defeat the purpose of your original request "query for id=1".  Take a look at this question for details on sorting arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941357/ios-sort-nsmutablearray-for-a-numeric-field/7941399#7941399  ** And use NSArray * myPeople = [string JSONValue];  as your starting point

Comment: Thank you maudicus. Your help is really appreciating. Many of my concepts are cleared. :-)

Comment: I am trying to make another view controller in which i am again adding a table view. in this table i want to add data from another URL. That URL consists of other key-value pairs but have same ID as of above in my question.Please tell me how i can achieve that , like , when i tap on a table row consisting of name , i will get the ID from that row and pass it to my other uiviewcontroller in same project and use it to populate table row of second view controller using that other URL.e.g,if 3rd row and corresponding ID is9, then my other table will be populated based on ID 9 values from 2nd URL.

Comment: Sounds like you have the logic all planned out.  Look for a tutorial online for using TableViews.  It wouldn't hurt to read through Apple's guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html     If you run into trouble ask another question with the code you have tried so far and how it is not working

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

I use this to get data from a webservice that spits out 50 records each having another 20 internal elements similar to the one you specify...

I use  the JSONKit in the following manner..(Had a look at SBJson a lot of user but i got confused from the word go.)

```
JSONDecoder *jArray = [[JSONDecoder alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *theObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
 theObject = [jArray objectWithData:theResponseData];//objectWithString:theResponseString
NSMutableArray *csArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain] ;

    for(id key in theObject)
    {
      if([key valueForKey:@"firstName"]  != Nil) 
      {
       ........
       }
     if([key valueForKey:@"lastName"]  != Nil) 
      {
       ........
       }
    }
```

check it out and let me know if it works or not.. By the way Great responses guys... Good

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. But i have already started my project using SBJSON.