# Get correct Node Json objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nodes

I'm parsing a Json object via `AFJSONRequestOperation`, the problem is, i cant get the correct value of the node.
The Json :

[Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-23.540788,-46.653991&radius=500&types=food&sensor=true&language=pt-BR&key=AIzaSyD0don13x8M0wJ_Sj1tUhdT60RQMoJpRVg)

I need to get only the temp value, inside the "results". I can get the results node, but the value inside it come as a array, how i can get the value for the name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON is invalid. Go to [this](http://jsonlint.com/) link, and check it.

What Snaker answered is pretty accurate, still:

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in results)
{
    NSString *name = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Crap, looks like my editing wasn't taken into account. But +1

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here, is that the results gives you a dictionnary of dictionnaries.
So you have to retrieve the dictionnary called "results", and then, once you got all the dictionnaries in it, you look for the names trough a loop.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958992/how-to-get-objects-from-a-json-array-in-iphone)

**UPDATE :**

```
dicionario = [dicionario objectForKey@"results"];
NSMutableArray *namesFromDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *elts in dicionario)
{
   [namesFromDict addObject:[elts objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

This should do.

Comment: Something like this?     `NSArray * resultados = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[_dicionario objectForKey:@"results"]];
    
    NSMutableDictionary * organizedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary * p in resultados) {
        [organizedData setValue:p forKey:[p valueForKey:@"id"]];
    }` The count of `organizedData` return me 20, but when i use `NSLog(@"%@",[organizedData objectForKey:@"name"]);` gives me null

Comment: Well, does `[p valueForKey:@"id"]` ever return a key called `@"name"`?